# Messaging Over Bluetooth

Tags: c#, .net, nokia-s40

There are some related posts but they are not answer to my problem.

I am planning to make some Desktop Application (Windows 7 x64) which will be requiring to send and receive SMS.

How can I connect to a cell-phone ( Any Nokia Phone with bluetooth s40,s60) and then when an SMS is received it can generate some event on the desktop app so that respective tasks can be done, and then reply the SMS from the Desktop App.

The texting should be done over bluetooth between phone and desktop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [32Feet.Net](http://32feet.net/) library for Bluetooth communication.  After you have  connected to `DialupNetworking` service of your cell phone you can use [AT command set](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/) to send/read SMSs

Comment: One more thing to take care of is that many phones do not allow third party applications to execute AT commands.

Comment: @zaibzaibi , Have you tried anything before asking a `simple working code`?

Comment: i am trying , but i  even failed to connect/or locate a bluetooth device  ,

Answer (score 0):

hi guys i found this [GSMCOMM](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) library , rater usefull and with sample code for C# .